# Is there an XML Editor with grid view similar to that of XMLSpy?

Tags: xml, editor, xmlspy

I have been testing out a few different xml editor/viewers and I can't seem to find any that have a feature that is comparable to XMLSpy's grid view.  Another feature I'd like to find, but is a deal breaker would be XMLSpy's ability to "Copy as Structured Text".  Haven't found anything similar to this either in the free varieties of xml editors/viewers.

Anybody ever worked with a free xml editor that has the grid view option like XMLSpy?

Comment: You could try http://xmlgrid.net/, an online service. It seems to work well enough but the website is showing signs of bitrot. There are broken links and the Forum link returning "internal server error". I didn't see an option for self hosting but it might be in there somewhere.

Comment: You can try [XiMpLe](http://www.ximple.cz)
It should have both your requirements (grid view + structure text).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[oXygen has a grid view for editing](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_grid_editor.html#xml_grid_editor_layout). oXygen is not free, but they do have a 30 day trial. Great editor for XML based work.  The price is reasonable for all the features.

> The XML document is displayed in the
>   XML Grid Editor as a structured layout
>   of nested tables in which the text
>   content can be modified without
>   directly interacting the XML tags.
>    considers the child elements
>   and attributes of the recurring
>   elements as columns. The tables can be
>   expanded and collapsed with a mouse
>   click to show or hide the elements as
>   needed. Also the document structure
>   can be changed easily with drag and
>   drop operations on the grid
>   components.

[image: Grid Editor with content completion]
[image: Grid Editor view]

Answer (score 19):

You can also use **XMLPad** tool and it's free!! You can download it from [here](http://www.wmhelp.com/)

Another one is [EditiX](http://www.editix.com/download.html)

Comment: The 2017 release  of EditiX does not seem to have a grid view.  Or I cannot find it.

Answer (score 8):

It seems the functionality you are looking for is already available in [WMHelp XMLPad](http://www.wmhelp.com/). It provides source, grid table preview. Software is free and development seems stopped in 2008.

Also, you can try [Foxe](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm) or [XML Copy Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xml-copy-editor/) or [Jaxe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxe/) or [CAMV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/camprocessor/)

Comment: In the future, try to add a link to the software you are referencing in your answer.

Comment: sure @j0k I will take care.

Answer (score 6):

Liquid's grid view is limited. you can't select multiple cells for copying an pasting.
I would go with Oxygen or XMLSpy. Stylus studio is also a decent option.

Comment: Stylus Studio costs $695 per license. ($99 for non-comercial)

Answer (score 6):

There appears to be a product called XML Marker that claims to have this as well.

http://symbolclick.com/

Never tried it.

Answer (score 6):

Liquid XML Studio has an [XML grid editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML-Editor.aspx). Each section can be viewed as a tree or a table. The Table view allows data to be cut and pasted from tabular data sources ie Excel, SQL Server management studio etc.

[image: Liquid XML Studio - DTD Grid Editor]

Comment: Are each columns sortable?

Comment: £195 for basic version.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Xsemmel and it is open source: https://xsemmel.codeplex.com

Comment: XSemmel failed for us by loading a UTF-16 file and saving it as UTF-8. Deal-breaker for us, YMMD

Comment: Xsemmel's can view XML as text, tree, and grid.  But the 09-APR-2017 release seems to lack the ability to keep the text and grid views "in sync".  In contrast, the product does keep tree and text views "in sync".  I'm using "in sync" to mean, you cursor around in the text view, then when you toggle to the the grid view it "auto expands" the XML elements in the grid view to match the text view cursor location.  Altova XMLSpy has this feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XML_editors for all available editors.

Comment: That page does not even contain the word "grid" - so, why the upvotes?

Answer (score 2):

[XML Marker](http://symbolclick.com/) is a great tool that I've used for years.  Well, that is, the old, free version (v1.1).  The current version 2.2 is no longer free: $50 individual, $125 commercial.  I find that price insane.  Same with [Liquid XML](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/) looks even nicer, but with an even insanerer[sic] price of $100/$300.  I'm surprised there aren't better free or even reasonably priced (<$20 IMHO) editors out there.  I'm tempted to write one, charge $5, and make a killing by sheer volume. ;-)

[Addendum:] I just downloaded [Xsemmel](https://xsemmel.codeplex.com/), recommended by another commenter.  It's free & open source, and so far it looks pretty good!  I'm going to give this a run for a while.