# how to pass xml data to gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

Recently i am stuck with a problem during my development.I have some xml values in a variable (not in a seperate file).I transform the xml using xslt and displayed them using xml control in my webpage.NOw my requirement has been changed and I supposed to display the xml values in Gridview instead of xml control.

```
string getval= //some stuff where webservice returns xml.
// here I specified content to xmldynamic control
xmldynamic.TransformSource=//my xslt comes here..
```

Now I want to display the transformed XML in gridview.Is it possible...If possible how..
I surfed through net and identified that if xml is in a file, then xml data source can be used,transformed and define datasource to gridview.But in my case its in a variable.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for XMLDataSource at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource(v=vs.110).aspx. That has a 'Data' property which could be used into of the 'DataFile' property.

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of 3rd party Class / Software that does that.

For example for web an this is a powerfull app maybe you dont want this extensive app on your side but consider ExtJS

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/

///

Also check this old topic for more

[Is there an XML Editor with grid view similar to that of XMLSpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609112/is-there-an-xml-editor-with-grid-view-similar-to-that-of-xmlspy)

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

1.) Load the XML data in a `StringReader`

2.) feed this  `StringReader` object to `ReadXml()` method of `DataSet`

3.) Now bind this  `DataSet` to your `GridView`.
    This step is always tricky ( May be) as depending on the XML format Many times I needed to modify it slightly as : `ds.Tables[0];` or `ds.Tables[1];` etc...

Sample:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Cameras>
  <Camera>
    <Model>Canon EOS-1D</Model>
    <Price>$5219</Price>
  </Camera>
  <Camera>
    <Model>Canon EOS-1D Mark IV</Model>
    <Price>$5000</Price>
  </Camera>
</Cameras>";

StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml); // Step 1
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(sr); // Step 2
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // Step 3
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: So after transformation, are you getting a final XML ?

Comment: Flopscientist.....as u see in my code above I received xml and transformed in the earlier steps itself..now I want to make that xml data as dataset which ll make me to pass the same as datasource to grid...

Comment: Yes if after transforming/modifications u get your final XML, then pass this xml to StringReader in Step 1